# cualquierClase.class cannot be opened because it does not exist - error al configurar Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

**Hola, necesito de su apoyo.** Estoy configurando Spring JPA, obtengo este **error** indicando que no encuentra mi clase
repositorio :

```
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Cannot parse com.icoronado.security.repository.UsuarioRepository metadata.; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/icoronado/security/repository/UsuarioRepository.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist`
```

Mi clase **dataConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.icoronado.security.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.icoronado.security.service")
public class WebDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=seguridadDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("mssqlserver");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.icoronado.security.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Mi clase **repository**

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends Repository<users, String> {

    users findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Mi clase **dominio(entidad)**: Los nombres de la clase y atributos son los mismos que en mi base de datos

```
@Entity
@Table
public class users {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

Gracias por el apoyo, en realidad estoy aprendiendo spring security, ya e realizado autenticación jdbc, pero quería poder customizar y extraer la data y guardarla con jpa.

**Actualización:**
Este es mi clase donde configuro la jerarquia WebApplicationContext **

```
package com.icoronado.security;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{SecurityConfig.class, WebDataConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Y aquí esta mi clase de **configuración MVC appConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.icoronado.security.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver view = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        view.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

}
```

Comment: Antes que nada, te recomiendo que pongas el código directamente en vez de imágenes. Es mucho más complicado intentar debuggar algo teniendo que abrir 5 imágenes que pudiendo verlo todo en pantalla, y mucha gente va a ignorar o downvotear tu pregunta debido a eso.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, en realidad soy nuevo con esto de las preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto. Yo uso EntityManagerFactory en lugar de LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. Me comentas. Saludos

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.icoronado.security.repository")

public class WebDataConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=seguridadDB");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("mssqlserver");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.icoronado.security.repository");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
    return properties;
}
}
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

Comment: puedes subir la implementación de UsuarioRepository? Deberías tener algo así.public class UsuarioRepositoryImpl implements UsuarioRepository. Con la anotacion de repository y la anoitacion de persistence context

Comment: No tengo implementaciones. Con la anotación @EnableJpaRepositories debería crear instancias de proxy para esta interfaz: UsuarioRepository, luego en mi clase service inyectaría la dependencias.

Comment: EnableJpaRepositories Lo que hace esto es escanear en busca de repositorios. Pero si no hay una implementación marcada como repository no va a encontrar nada y por lo lanto al inyectar dará error. El contenedor de objectos crea instancias de aquellas clases marcadas con Service, Controller, Repository, Component etc.